# url rewrite and redirect - php

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I recently developed a web site using php which accepts a id as its input via get.
http://website.com/profile.php?id=123. its the old fashion way, I've seen sites use pretty url's like http://website.com/username.html

So in order to archive this, i managed to do some research and end up with this code blow.
Also i'm passing the username in the query string.
http://website.com/profile.php?id=123&username=test_user
the parameter **ID** is only used as a input for the **profile.php**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST}      /profile.php     [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}     ^id=([^&]+)&username=([^&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^.*                 http://%{HTTP_HOST}/%2.html [R=301,L]
```

The final output i seek is http://website.com/username.html

Is their anything wrong in this ? this doesn't seem to work. Am i doing something wrong ? if so please be kind to let me know where my error lies. Thank you.

Comment: Are you trying to redirect username.html to profile.php?id=XXX or vice versa?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /profile.php\?id=([^&]+)&username=([^&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/%2.html? [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/([^/.]+)\.html$ profile.php?id=$1&username=$2 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Comment: Sorry just came back online. As you noticed in other answer it is better to keep both id and username in URI. See the URL of this stackoverflow question which uses both id and question title. I strongly recommend this URI structure to you. (Have edited my answer acordingly)

Comment: Thanks. Its fine. i'll check it out and get back. The only problem with going to other folders is that i have to include all the styles and js again.

I like your answer better, i'll get back.
Thanks again.

Comment: For js and css recommended way is to use absolute path in your css, js, images files rather than a relative one. Which means you have to make sure path of these files start either with `http://` or a slash `/`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this rule:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^profile/([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+).html/?$ profile.php?id=$1&username=$2 [L]
```

then you should be able to use

```
http://website.com/profile/123/username.html
```

as the URL. You can ignore the `profile` part but I don't recomment it because it would clash with other URLs of your website.

If you only need the username, use

```
RewriteRule ^profile/([^/\.]+).html/?$ profile.php?username=$2 [L]
```

and the URL would be

```
http://website.com/profile/username.html
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you for the answer.
I only seek to get the username, for example my url will look something like http://website.com/username.html

Thank you.

Comment: Then how would you pass the user id to the PHP file? Is your PHP code looks up for the username and fetch the id?

Comment: it uses the the parameter id to fetch the information from the database

Comment: The .htaccess rewrite only changes the format of your URL. It does not automagically pass userid when it is not supplied in the URL.